# In Vuejs i have to delete a section when i click on "X" but there is some error with it

Tags: vue.js, task-management

image of output with error on console

[image]

heres the picture of code where its showing error

[image]

Comment: Please add the sections.vue code as a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There is neither an attribute called tab nor Index in your code
Define a data section and add those attributes

```
data() {
 return {
  tab: null,
  Index: null
 }
}
```

Also I don't see any usage of those variables other than in `console.log`.
So if that's true then no need define the `data()` section. You can directly emit the parameter like

```
methods: {
  removeSection(idx) {
   this.$emit('remove', idx);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't ask you to share the whole source code. Did you check the comment properly